# Using IPtables to block outgoing traffic to a TAP interface from a LAN IP address or subnet

Tags: iptables

How can I configure IPtables to block outgoing traffic to a TAP interface from an IP or subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded a solution for this:

under *filter:

iptables -A FORWARD -s (source ip) -o tap0 -DROP

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need something like this:

iptables -A OUTPUT -s (source ip) -d (destination ip) -p (protocol) --j REJECT

And you can use --j DROP instead, to not send ICMP unreachable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately you're give solution didn't work.